# In The Boy Who Cried Werewolf, where is Jordan's mother?

Tags: the-boy-who-cried-werewolf

Is there an explicit reason for her mom’s absence, and is her little brother merely adopted or a step/half-brother?

Comment: Ok then? I’ll break it to one question, ok?

Comment: The bloodline thing is weird. If anything, Jordan should be the step-daughter since she doesn't have the werewolf genes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [not explicitly stated where the mother is](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MissingMom), but I'm pretty sure the implication is that she died a few years ago. Lots of talk of "I miss her too" and trying to set dad up on dates.

---

That being said, Nickelodeon issued [a press-release](https://www.rbr.com/nickelodeon-to-air-vampire-themed-teen-movie-ahead-of-halloween/) describing the film. The mother's fate is confirmed for us.

> *Jordan Sands (Justice) is an awkward, allergy-prone 17-year-old,
> forced to be the woman of the house **after her mother’s death**.  Her
> father, David (Matt Winston, Little Miss Sunshine ), is struggling to
> make ends meet, while her younger brother, Hunter (Chase Ellison,
> Tooth Fairy), drives his family crazy with gory pranks.  Things start
> to look up when they inherit their Great Uncle Dragomir Vucovic’s
> castle in Wolfsberg, Romania, which could relieve them of their
> financial woes.*

We don't have any indication that Jordan's younger brother is anything other than her biological sibling and the offspring of her two parents.